# Filters in Oracle APEX 4.2

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 4.2.

I would like to know if there is a way to customize the filters in the interactive report to have the possibility to select multiple filters entries like in Excel, as shown in this image:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is runtime behaviour. Use the Actions menu, choose *Filter*.

Select your column, choose operator "In", choose multiple values, which will be separated by comma.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/customizing-interactive-reports-as-an-end-user.htm#HTMDB25950